# Why is $x^2\ln\sqrt{x}$ equal to $\frac{x^2}{2}\ln x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My textbook jumps from $$x^2\ln\sqrt{x}$$
to
$$\frac{x^2}{2}\ln x$$
What intermediate steps occur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Properties of logarithm

$$\log(x^a) = a\log(x)$$

Thence

$$\log(\sqrt{x}) = \log(x^{1/2}) = \frac{1}{2}\log(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate steps are as follows:
$$x^2\ln \sqrt{x}$$
$$=x^2\ln x^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln x$$

This follows from the [power rule](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.htm) of logarithms.

> $$\ln x^y=y\ln x$$